# can't install pywin32 or pip install is not working

Tags: python, pip, pywin32

I am trying to install the pywin32 for my window service but unfortunately, I receive this error. I am also trying to install another module but the error was still the same. I'm wondering if it's a package error or python error as a whole. because even though I'm trying to install another module, the module 'typing' has attribute 'NoReturn' error has still appeared.

```
File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir, enum
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 38, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.tenacity import retry, stop_after_delay, wait_fixed
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 186, in <module>
    class RetryError(Exception):
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 193, in RetryError
    def reraise(self) -> t.NoReturn:
AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 'NoReturn'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `NoReturn` attribute was not added to the `typing` module until Python 3.6.2, you most likely have 3.6.0, which won't work. You'll need to upgrade to Python 3.6.2 or higher.